# C# projects execution failure

Tags: c#, execution

I´m new in the manage of this tool, I try it with php code and every thing works fine, but now I want to use it with C# projects and the execution failure.

First show a message "SonarQube.CSharp.CodeAnalisys.Runner stop running" and this are the details:

```
Firma con problemas:
  Nombre del evento de problema:    APPCRASH
  Nombre de la aplicación:  SonarQube.CSharp.CodeAnalysis.Runner.exe
  Versión de la aplicación: 0.7.0.0
  Marca de tiempo de la aplicación: 553798c2
  Nombre del módulo con errores:    KERNELBASE.dll
  Versión del módulo con errores:   6.1.7601.17514
  Marca de tiempo del módulo con errores:   4ce7bafa
  Código de excepción:  e0434352
  Desplazamiento de excepción:  0000b727
  Versión del sistema operativo:    6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Id. de configuración regional:    10250
  Información adicional 1:  0a9e
  Información adicional 2:  0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Información adicional 3:  0a9e
  Información adicional 4:  0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Lea nuestra declaración de privacidad en línea:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0c0a

Si la declaración de privacidad en línea no está disponible, lea la declaración de privacidad sin conexión:
  C:\Windows\system32\es-ES\erofflps.txt
```

Somebody could help me?

Comment: Please describe in details, what tool and framework are you using, what exactly causes the exception. The more details - the better.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help,

I already fix my problem, the reason was that I have to update my .NET Framework to 4.5.1 versión and run again without fails

With this solution I close this topic

Claudia

Comment: Just delete your question, please.